# Rails button to duplicate object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I need to put a blue button to duplicate and save a new object with the same info, just duplicate the line.

I try with the following but when i click the blue button just go to the show of that line
I dont know what i missing (maybe a lot)

[image]

gastos.html.erb

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary mr-2 command-delete">
       <%= link_to '', gasto, action: dup,  class: "fa fa-trash fa-fw text-light" %>
</button>
```

gastos_controller.rb

```
def dup
    @gasto_dup = Gasto.find(params[:id]).dup
    render :new
end
```

Logs when i click the blue button

```
Started GET "/gastos/152" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-07-28 16:03:57 -0400
Processing by GastosController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"152"}
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Gasto Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "gastos".* FROM "gastos" WHERE "gastos"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 152], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/gastos_controller.rb:135:in `set_gasto'
  Rendering gastos/show.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered gastos/show.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 2.9ms | Allocations: 91)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
Completed 200 OK in 133ms (Views: 102.7ms | ActiveRecord: 2.4ms | Allocations: 17541)
```

Comment: share the logs of server, I think the request is going to some other controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just linking the `show` action.

You can't add an `action: :dup` argument to `link_to`, that doesn't do anything. The 2nd argument is the URL, `action: :dup` is just being dumped into the DOM as a `action="dup"` attribute on the `<a>` tag.

Instead of this...

```
link_to '', gasto, action: dup ...
```

You need

```
link_to '', dup_gasto_path(gasto), ...
```

The above assumes your routes are correctly configured.

Comment: thanks that was the problem and in the controller a little modification
@gasto = Gasto.find(params["format"].to_i).dup

Comment: @Poluxland That's incorrect, you should never use `params['format']` that way. Your routes are not configured correctly, if that is how the record's ID is being passed in.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not super familiar here but it might be worth a try use `.clone` instead of `.dup`.

https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/11/dup-vs-clone/

> Both methods copy an object, the difference is that dup doesn’t copy
> the object attributes.

Comment: i got the same problem with .clone or .dup